# How can I use Federated Login SSO on Google App Engine across application versions?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, openid

Federated Login on Google App Engine (both Java and Python) does not transition across application versions. `CreateLoginURL` ignores attributes such as `openid.realm` (which would allow me to set a wildcard on the domain). A version's sub-domain results in a different session than the main application (or a different version's session). Is this a flaw in Google's session tracking? Or is this a flaw in the Federated login? Or am I doing something wrong (or not doing something right)?

It sounds like I need to handle sessions and OpenID interactions myself to overcome this limitation, but I wanted to ping the Stackoverflow folks before I reinvented the wheel.

Examples in Python or Java are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default GAE sessions are based on cookies (in GAE production its named ACSID or SACSID) which are NOT subdomain cookies.

About subdomain cookies: https://serverfault.com/questions/153409/can-subdomain-example-com-set-a-cookie-that-can-be-read-by-example-com

To make this work you should write your own custom session handler.

Comment: So there is no way to make the GAE sessions subdomain cookies? Oh my kingdom for a leading dot :(